# C++ invalid pointer error

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm getting invalid point error from the code below I don't see why. All I'm trying to do is to delete free some strings on the heap from a vector:

```
void func() {
    vector<string>* vec = new vector<string>;
    vec->push_back(*(new string("1")));
    vec->push_back(*(new string("2")));

    for(vector<string>::iterator itr = vec->begin(); itr != vec->end(); ++itr)
    {
        string* ptr = &(*itr);
        delete(ptr);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: is it because push_back creates a copy of the string?

Comment: `vec->push_back(*(new string("1")));` = memory leak

Comment: because `push_back() ` creates a copy and leaves the string on the heap out of reference, correct?

Comment: If you really want to allocate on the heap, safer to use http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_container.html

Comment: @user1861088, correct

Answer (score 6):

Your error is because the *element* isn't dynamically allocated; the *vector* is. What you're trying to do would require:

```
void func() 
{
    vector<string*> vec;
    vec.push_back(new string("1"));
    vec.push_back(new string("2"));

    for(vector<string*>::iterator itr = vec.begin(); itr != vec.end(); ++itr)
    {
        string* ptr = *itr;
        delete(ptr);
    }
}
```

But honestly I see little reason to do this. As-written your code not only attempts to delete memory it never actually allocated, it leaks what it allocations it *did* make.

There *are* reasons to store pointers to objects in a vector like this (such as the objects being actually from another container somewhere else and you need a temporary list of them for a custom-sort operation without disturbing the original content), but something tells me you're a ways-off from having such a need.

Comment: I understand. Situation is I cannot use a vector of pointers. Well, I was confused about some concepts. But I think I get it now.

Comment: You *can* use a vector of pointers.  But you probably have no reason to.

Comment: @user1861088 Charles is correct. there *are* reasons to use a vector of pointers (I cite one in my answer), but I don't think such uses are applicable to your current needs.

Comment: why not? sorry I am new to C++. If I instead return hard copies everywhere instead of pointers, wouldn't that be a bad practice because a lot of time is spent creating copies? Why using pointers is not preferred in C++ in this situation?

Comment: @user1861088, you don't need to return hard copies.  C++ has *references*.

Comment: First, regarding pointers owning resources, see [this simple doc](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6101039/Modern%20C%2B%2B.pdf) that sums it up nicely. If you must use pointers, and those pointers *own* the resources they point to, give them brains (make them smart pointers). Otherwise, tread *very, very carefully.* The example reason I cite for using a vector of naked pointers is considerable because the pointers in the vector *would not own the resources they point to*. Hard to picture, I know, but important.

Comment: @Charles Salvia but if I create an object on the local stack of a function return a reference to it, once the function returns will not the object be gone ?

Comment: @user1861088, that is a different problem than accessing an element that is stored in a container.  In general, you really need to understand C++ ownership semantics if you are every going to use pointers.  If you need to return an object from a function, return it by value.  C++11 has move semantics which usually will ensure the object is moved, rather than copied.  Otherwise, if you're not using C++11, considering returning a smart pointer or (less preferably) using an "output value parameter".

Comment: got it. thanks for the comments guys! I'm starting to accept the fact that C++ is way more complicated (and smarter for that matter) than C + STL, lol.

Comment: @user1861088 Absolutely it is. it has come a **long** way since the original C++ w/STL many moons ago. The 1300+ pages of the C++11 standards document is in itself a testimony to how much better it is defined.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, the line

```
vec->push_back(*(new string("1")));
```

is causing a memory leak.  The value returned from `new string("1")` is a pointer to a newly allocated string object.  But when you dereference it and insert it into the vector, a *copy* of the heap-allocated object is created and inserted.  However, the actual string object you originally allocated on the heap is leaked.

Essentially, your vector is storing string objects by value, not pointers to string objects.  The copy of the string object that is inserted into the vector is NOT a heap allocated object (not an object allocated with `new`).  And of course, you cannot `delete` something that wasn't allocated with `new`. So when you call `delete(ptr)` you are causing undefined behavior.

What you seem to want here is a:

`vector<string*>* vec = new vector<string*>;`

However, in general I don't see any compelling reason why you are allocating everything on the heap.  In C++ it is preferable to use stack allocation and containers with value semantics whenever feasible, unless you have some reason why you need heap allocation (e.g. a container of polymorphic objects, in which case you should use smart pointers anyway).  Generally, when new C++ programmers use heap-allocated objects and the `new` keyword all over the place, it is a sign that they are poorly transliterating a programming style imported from a managed language like Java or C#.

Answer (score 3):

No you're not - your vector stores `string` objects, not pointers to `string` objects. That's why you have the `*` in your `push_back` call - you are dereferencing the returned pointer.

You are adding a *copy* of the dynamic string you create with `new` and that dynamic string is lost, since you never store the pointer that `new` returns.